# Chromium broswer doesnt open google and says its untrusted

Tags: raspbian, connection, internet, chromium, web-browsers

Hello I need to install an extension for chromium for my project on raspberry pi but chromium says that the google extensions and pretty much any google sites are untrusted I tried reinstalling certificates importing/exporting them and none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your local time on your Pi?

At command line:

```
date
```

Maybe it's off. If so, use the raspi-config utility to adjust timezone.